# SQLite Database wont compile correctly?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating an android app which monitors attendance, although I am getting errors when I attempt to login with a users details from the sqlite database saying a column doesnt exist.

DBHelper.class

```
package uk.ac.qub.qubattend;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QUBAttendanceDB";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_StudentInfo = "studentinfo";
    // Table Columns names
    // id column
    private static final String KEY_ID = "StudentId";
    // question column
    private static final String KEY_PASS = "password";
    // answer column
    private static final String KEY_WEEK1 = "Week1";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK2 = "Week2";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK3 = "Week3";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK4 = "Week4";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK5 = "Week5";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK6 = "Week6";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK7 = "Week7";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK8 = "Week8";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK9 = "Week9";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK10 = "Week10";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK11 = "Week11";
    private static final String KEY_WEEK12 = "Week12";

    // Database constant
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

    /**
     * Method to check the db name and version
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        // Create Table method
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_StudentInfo + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_PASS + " TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK1
                + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK2 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK3 + "TEXT, "
                + KEY_WEEK4 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK5 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK6
                + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK7 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK8 + "TEXT, "
                + KEY_WEEK9 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK10 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK11
                + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK12 + "TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        // implementing add questions method
        addAttendance();

    }

    /**
     * Add Questions Method using Question Object with question, 4 options and
     * correct answer
     */
    private void addAttendance() {
        Student s1 = new Student("40023798", "letmeinhere", "90", "80", "0",
                "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0");
        this.addStudent(s1);

    }

    // Checking that existing database table called TABLE_QUEST is dropped
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_StudentInfo);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * method for adding a new question into the database
     * 
     * @param quest
     */
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, student.getStudentId());
        values.put(KEY_PASS, student.getPassword());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK1, student.getWeek1());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK2, student.getWeek2());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK3, student.getWeek3());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK4, student.getWeek4());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK5, student.getWeek5());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK6, student.getWeek6());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK7, student.getWeek7());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK8, student.getWeek8());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK9, student.getWeek9());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK10, student.getWeek10());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK11, student.getWeek11());
        values.put(KEY_WEEK12, student.getWeek12());
        // Inserting Row with question

        dbase.insert(TABLE_StudentInfo, null, values);
    }

    /**
     * Method to move questions in database to an ArrayList
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents() {
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_StudentInfo;
        dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Student student = new Student();
                student.setStudentId(cursor.getString(0));
                student.setPassword(cursor.getString(1));
                student.setWeek1(cursor.getString(2));
                student.setWeek2(cursor.getString(3));
                student.setWeek3(cursor.getString(4));
                student.setWeek4(cursor.getString(5));
                student.setWeek5(cursor.getString(6));
                student.setWeek6(cursor.getString(7));
                student.setWeek7(cursor.getString(8));
                student.setWeek8(cursor.getString(9));
                student.setWeek9(cursor.getString(10));
                student.setWeek10(cursor.getString(11));
                student.setWeek11(cursor.getString(12));
                student.setWeek12(cursor.getString(13));
                studentList.add(student);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return question list
        return studentList;
    }

    /**
     * Method to Check Database number of rows
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public int rowcount() {
        int row = 0;
        // select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_StudentInfo;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row = cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

Below is the log which displays the error but I dont know why its throwing the error :

```
01-17 16:26:51.616: E/SQLiteLog(1667): (1) table studentinfo has no column named Week8
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667): Error inserting StudentId=40023798 Week8=0 Week9=0 Week4=0 Week5=0 password=letmeinhere Week6=0 Week7=0 Week3=0 Week2=80 Week12=0 Week1=90 Week11=0 Week10=0
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table studentinfo has no column named Week8 (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO studentinfo(StudentId,Week8,Week9,Week4,Week5,password,Week6,Week7,Week3,Week2,Week12,Week1,Week11,Week10) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at uk.ac.qub.qubattend.DBHelper.addStudent(DBHelper.java:109)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at uk.ac.qub.qubattend.DBHelper.addAttendance(DBHelper.java:73)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at uk.ac.qub.qubattend.DBHelper.onCreate(DBHelper.java:62)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at uk.ac.qub.qubattend.DBHelper.onUpgrade(DBHelper.java:83)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
01-17 16:26:51.656: E/SQLiteDatabase(1667):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
```

If anyone knows why it is not picking up column 8 I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

All of the `KEY_WEEK...` values have `"TEXT, "` appended after them, not `" TEXT, "`, and so your column and datatype names should be running together.

You may be better served either using `StringBuilder` (faster) or `String.format()` (easier to read), rather than string concatenation.

Comment: Or for (1:12) loop considering they are all of type TEXT. (Also moving it into different class so that these string manipulations can be tested (e.g SqlQueryBuilder) is not far fetched especially if you'll need to create such queries more often than once or alternatively if suits your needs a library like http://www.jooq.org/. In any case all that is beyond the scope of your question - just offering options/suggestions)

Comment: Thanks! il give it a go.